# ошибка SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<',

Tags: javascript

При попытке обработать файл `.xlsx` выдает ошибку:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

в строчке `eval(ajaxRequest.responseText);`.

Вот функция, которая не работает...

```js
function ajaxUploadFile(form)
{
    var ajaxRequest;
    try {
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e) {
        try {
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
                alert("Contact your SA!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (ajaxRequest.readyState == 4)
        {
            eval(ajaxRequest.responseText);
            //console.log(ajaxRequest.responseText);
        }
    }
    var formData = new FormData(form);
    ajaxRequest.open("POST", thisFileName, true);
    //ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data")
    ajaxRequest.send(formData);
}
```

не понимаю, в чем может быть ошибка

Comment: Ну попробуйте раскомментировать `console.log(ajaxRequest.responseText);` и поставить этот код перед `eval`. И покажите нам, что выводится.

Comment: Если коротко, то, что вы пытаетесь преобразовать в eval имеет синтаксическую ошибку

Comment: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'` означает, что вместо файла, который пытаетесь разобрать, сервер вернул html. Скорей всего страницу с сообщением об ошибке

Comment: @DmitryKozlov Ну да, скорее всего так. И логирование это сразу покажет.